# Scattering Cross section confusion

Tags: kinetic-theory

I am reading David Tong's excellent lecture notes on kinetic theory, but I am confused in the derivation of the hard-sphere scattering cross-sectional area
[image: Figure 5: Hard Sphere Scattering]

He uses figure 5 to discuss the scattering angle of the incident hard-sphere. Both spheres are identical.

I have two things I am confused about.

Firstly, doesn't this diagram assume that the particle that is moving collides at the bottom? Wouldn't it collide like this instead:

[image: Collision happens not necessarily at the bottom of the moving particle]

And Finally, the result he obtains for the scattering cross section is $\pi \frac{d^2 }{4}$ where $d$ is the diameter of the spheres. However, shouldn't the scattering cross section be $ \pi d^2$ instead? This is the value that is used when deriving mean free path length in a first course in thermodynamics.

Comment: You are correct on your first question - that is how you in fact proceed to calculate the differential cross section. As for part 2, again you are correct - $b = 2d$ is needed for no scattering to occur.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. This leaves me confused though since there seem to be two different answers to the scattering cross-section. Do it using figure 5 and you get $\pi \frac{d^2}{4}$ but do it another way you get $\pi d^2$ which one is right?